# Server Sent Event with React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, real-time, server-sent-events

i am trying to integrate server sent event in React-Native , so i am using this package https://github.com/binaryminds/react-native-sse#readme

and this is the code  , i pust it in the main stack of the app and

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const url = new URL("https://your-sse-server.com/.well-known/mercure");

    const es = new EventSource(url, {
      headers: {
        UserId: "123",
        Authorization: "123",
        "X-Api-Key": "0242ac120002",
      },
      method: "PATCH",
    });

    const listener: EventSourceListener = event => {
      if (event.type === "open") {
        console.log("Open SSE connection.");
      } else if (event.type === "waiting") {
        console.log(`Received waiting`);
      } else if (event.type === "success") {
        console.log(`Received success`);
      } else if (event.type === "error") {
        console.error("Connection error:", event.message);
      } else if (event.type === "exception") {
        console.error("Error:", event.message, event.error);
      }
    };

    es.addEventListener("open", listener);
    es.addEventListener("waiting", listener);
    es.addEventListener("success", listener);

    return () => {
      es.removeAllEventListeners();
      es.close();
    };
  }, []);
```

the issue i have when i start the app this line printed

```js
 LOG  Open SSE connection.
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Open SSE connection.
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Open SSE connection.
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Received waiting
 LOG  Open SSE connection.
```

the issue that  this lines  LOG  Received waiting always printed one time without delay  , and request to the https://your-sse-server.com/.well-known/mercure will be fired again this cyle will contine , api work on postman well , it return waiting every 2 second

Comment: I suggest using `react-native-event-source`. I used `react-native-sse` aswell in a project and it only gave me old values stacked upon each other and a 3 week headache. When i switched over to `react-native-event-source`, my problem was solved immediately.

Comment: i already used it too but same issue , api called and it return all  Received waiting in one time